# How to use regexp query filter in ElasticSearch Field Names?

Tags: elasticsearch

For given below test data of `ElasticSearch` index, how do we eliminate the field name(s) containing UUID or any regex expression?

```
{
  "_index": "twitter",
  "_type": "test_data",
  "_id": "05ed7d0d-ec9e-4e48-a5a3-cdef11e7be28",
  "_score": 8.843938,
  "_source": {
    "test_data-created_time": 1485858118,
    "test_data-status": 1,
    "cluster-05ed7d0d-ec9e-4e48-a5a3-cdef11e7be28": "ElasticSearch"
  }
}
```

I am able to achieve this requirement with below query, but there are many fields matching UUID as part of field name itself. Anyone have better thoughts on how to optimize?

```
GET /twitter/test_data/_search
{
  "_source": {
    "excludes": [
    "cluster-05ed7d0d-ec9e-4e48-a5a3-cdef11e7be28"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if there is a way to exclude patterns other than wildcards. If all your UUID fields have a pattern to them like a specific prefix, say cluster, you could use `cluster-*`. Otherwise, something like this could work if it doesn't conflict with other fields:

```
"_source": {
    "excludes": ["*-*-*-*-*"]}
```

Agree though that it is not a very clean solution.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Tried this solution, it is giving partial results as the index contains required fields too with 5 field separators: (-).